# spring boot not loading correct Jasypt application.properties for environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I am trying to implement Jasypt in my Spring Boot 1.4 application because it seems overkill to use Spring Cloud Config for a small app like this. However, I am clearly not understanding how Spring Boot determines which environment its running, and use the appropriate properties file.  I need to encrypt the datasource properties stored such as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myschema
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=ENC(ZwXHbQl^8c2U)
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
```

In my `project/config/` directory I have three files:

- `application.properties`: single entry of: `spring.profiles.active=local`
- `application-local.properties`: config values for develop, including local db credentials
- `application-test.properties`: config values for test env such as db credentials, etc
- `application-prod.properties`: config values for production env such as db credentials, etc

I am importing Jasypt via:

> compile group: 'com.github.ulisesbocchio', name:
>   'jasypt-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.7'

I run local Spock / Goovy integration tests, so I annotate my Base Test class with

> @ActiveProfiles("local, test")

But that didn't seem to pickup the properties file.
<**FIXED**> by adding `@ActiveProfiles(["local", "test"])`

I added the **/config/application.properties** file to set the

> spring.profiles.active=local
>   jasypt.encryptor.password=

I have looked at the documentation for how Jasypt works, so I can try and understand how to encrypt my db credentials per environment.  Also, I have been able to figure out how to get the proper properties file loaded to test the encryption yet.

**UPDATE**

It would appear that the proper *.properties file is being loaded now (thanks to the great feedback!) but the database password is either not found or not able to be decrypted.  I see the following in the logs:

```
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : String Encryptor custom Bean not found with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'. Initializing String Encryptor based on properties with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource commandLineArgs [to EncryptableEnumerablePropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
 eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.context.config.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [file:./config/application-local.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [file:./config/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
 .c.EncryptablePropertySourcesInitializer : Created Encryptable Property Source 'EncryptedProperties' from locations: [classpath:application.properties]

 Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.algorithm, using default value: PBEWithMD5AndDES
 c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.keyObtentionIterations, using default value: 1000
c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.poolSize, using default value: 1
c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.providerName, using default value: SunJCE
c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.saltGeneratorClassname, using default value: org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator
c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.stringOutputType, using default value: base64
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

According to this line:

```
Property Source 'EncryptedProperties' from locations:[classpath:application.properties]
```

It almost seems like we have to explicitly declare which properties files to search for encrypted values in the @EnableEncryptableProperties( ) annotation, but that doesn't seem to take a list of files or property values, nor do I find anyone saying that needs to be done.

Comment: For starters, `@ActiveProfiles("local, test")` will activate a profile named `local, test`, not both `local` and `test` profiles. I guess what you wanted was `@ActiveProfiles({"local", "test"})`

Comment: Also, instead of checking in encrypted credentials into source control, you can use *Environment Variables*.

Comment: looks like I can't pass in via {} because my base class is Groovy and that complains that the comma means a new line is expected.

Comment: You might want to mention the fact that you are using Groovy and not plain java, as that quite influence the answering of the question.

Comment: Thank you.  I am actually using Groovy/Spock for my testing and Java for my production code.

Answer (score 3):

Using `{}` for annotations with multiple values will not work in `Groovy`, try `@ActiveProfiles(["local", "test"])` or `@ActiveProfiles(["local", "test"] as String[])`. See [Arrays](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_arrays)

Answer (score 2):

if you have set `spring.profiles.active=local` in `application.properties` then you dont have to use @ActiveProfiles annotation it will look for `application-local.properties`

The `spring.profiles.active` property follows the same ordering rules as other properties, the highest PropertySource will win. This means that you can specify active profiles in `application.properties` then replace them using the command line switch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, I am now seeing my application-local.properties file being used except for the encrypted value.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the Spring docs, it should be: @ActiveProfiles({"local", "test"}). Can you try it?! Refer more details on here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Hope this help!

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned I am using Groovy for my tests, so I adjusted for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you myst try Bootstrapping Jasypt !!!
It's needed Jasypt to decrypt encrypted properties before config-server starts pulling configurations from config repository.

bootstrap.yaml

```
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true

spring.application.name=config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/jamesmedice
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=james@medici.com
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=ENC(#################)
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
jasypt.encryptor.password=superkey


@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class JasyptSpringCloudBootstrapConfiguration {

     @Configuration
     @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "jasypt.encryptor.bootstrap", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
     @Import(EnableEncryptablePropertiesConfiguration.class)
     protected static class BootstrappingEncryptablePropertiesConfiguration {

     }
}
```

@ConditionalOnClass('BootstrapApplicationListener')  makes sure the configuration will be effective in spring cloud based environments only. @ConditionalOnProperty(“spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled” ...) ensures that it’s not the case, once is provided the jasypt.encryptor.bootstrap configuration in order to explicitly disable ‘bootstrapping Jasypt’ , Jasypt will be auto-configured as well.